# What ports are essential and should generally be allowed on a Linux system?

Tags: security, firewall, tcp, udp

I'm running a desktop computer, but one with high threat risk.

I've blocked all ports using a firewall except:

HTTP, HTTPS, DNS, one port for torrent client.

Do any common processes in distros like Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Debian use other ports that I need to allow?

Comment: This question is way too broad. What is your system used for? As a firewall, a NAS, a desktop, an embedded system, …? What applicatins are you using? No ports are generally essential. A Linux system works fine without any network connectivity. And ports don't have security risks (except for kernel bugs), but applications do. Open the ports you need and close the remaining ones.

Comment: There is no default setting. It strongly depends of what purpose you going to use the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, modern firewalls are 'stateful'.

Meaning you don't need to allow anything from outside as it will find out itself which are the answers to requests that you have made and let them in automatically.

So you don't need incoming HTTP or HTTPS, etc. explicitely unless you're hosting a webserver.

However, if you have a port forwarding for your torrent client, you indeed need to allow that, because there is no outgoing connection asking for a reply but indeed a new connection coming in from outside in that case.

In practice it should look more or less like this for starters (look up an iptables tutorial for details):

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID
2    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

Might be useful to allow ssh port besides a torrent port, but then make sure your ssh password is secure or use keys.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that. I thought that you had to allow both incoming and outgoing connection for HTTP, HTTPS and DNS. Now changed it.

Comment: You're blocking DNS.

Answer (score 0):

For a minimalist way of dealing with it:

Check ufw status, as superuser:

```
ufw status
```

if disabled, do:

```
ufw enable
```

This will block all incoming and allow all outgoing, and should be enough for all desktops.